# Embedded tweets sometimes loses its borders on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I am trying to display a set of responsive embedded tweets in rows of 2.

Below are the relevant pieces of code that has allowed me to get it to work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="tweets"></div>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
#tweets {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  max-width: 820px;
  width: 95%;
}
#tweets .row {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#tweets .row > .tweet {
  max-width: 520px;
  width: 49%;
}
#tweets .row > .tweet:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}
#tweets .row > .tweet:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}
#tweets .row > .tweet .twitter-tweet-rendered {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = (function() {
  // sample data
  var tweets = [
    '629488522752212992', '629487749200936961', '629488522752212992',
    '629487749200936961', '629488522752212992', '629487749200936961'
  ];

  var container = $('#tweets');
  var list = '';
  // build the necessary markup before rendering tweets
  for (var i = 0, even = true; i < tweets.length; i++, even = i % 2 === 0) {
    if (even) {
      list += '<div class="row">';
    }
    list += '<div class="tweet"></div>';
    if (!even) {
      list += '</div>';
    }
  }
  container.html(list);
  // render tweets 
  $.each(tweets, function(i) {
    var tweet = container.find('.tweet:eq(' + i + ')');
    twttr.widgets.createTweet(this, tweet[0], {
      'cards': 'none'
    });
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/yigucejice/edit?output

Now here's the problem: the tweets' borders are inconsistently being shown on different browsers. For example, sometimes the right border on some tweets is hidden in my IE 11 (as shown in the image below); or sometimes the bottom border on some tweets are hidden in my Firefox 39.0.

I would like the borders to always show on every browser.

Within the tweets, I have tried adjusting the styles of the iframe (.twitter-tweet-rendered) such as the margin and height, but have gotten no luck at solving the problem.

How can I fix this? If not, is there a way to turn off the borders?

[image]

**Solution**

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872018/1022914) below, I ended up modifying my JavaScript code as such:

```
twttr.widgets.createTweet(this, tweet, { 'cards': 'none' }).then(function(frame) {
    // remove EmbeddedTweet's border
    $(frame).contents().find('.EmbeddedTweet').css({ 'border': 'none' });
    // add border on the placeholder that holds the iframe
    tweet.addClass('border'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve the problem with border not disappear,

Reason the border disappear is the media screen size queries and in chrome border rendered correctly and show but in firefox it disappear, but in firefox if you reduce the page size from `100%` to `90%` the border appear and shows correctly.

There are 2 solutions

with pure CSS

reduce width `width: 49%;` to `width: 47%;`

```
#tweets .row > .tweet {
    max-width: 520px;
    width: 47%;
}
```

Or with jQuery,

add following code and set `margin: 1px` to `EmbeddedTweet` so border has space to appear/show.

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(".twitter-tweet-rendered").contents().find(".EmbeddedTweet").css("margin","1px");
  }, 3000); 
</script>
```

I set the time out `3000` so iframe load first and margin can be set because twitter iframe is cross domain.

**Note:** cannot apply css on iframe directly as its cross domain so jQuery or JavaScript is the only option.

I reproduce the error [Here](https://jsbin.com/voticazolo/1/edit?js,output) and applied jQuery solution

Comment: I don't think your edit was saved. And I was still having problems using `margin: 1px` in IE. So I ended with another solution using your jQuery approach shown above. Thanks.

Comment: @Mikey, you are right my edit didn't save but you can check here http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/tweeterfeed.html i don't wana post my personal site link in answer and its working in chrome and firefox and IE11 and give the page time to load coz i set time delay to apply margin on iframe